Increasing Lawn Slope against Foundation
First time homeowner here. Noticed water seeping into our newly finished basement after heavy rains. Found 1-2 areas around the foundation where the there’s a negative/near negative slope. My question is do I really have to spend $100 for a yard of silted topsoil, or can I get bags of regular topsoil from my locals supply store? Any help would be appreciated.

Also What type of fill to use to raise grade in back yard

For small/tiny areas use the bags, but it can be surprising how much it takes.  Buy one bag and see how far it goes, then decide.

I'm not sure what you're asking. We have no idea how much soil you need or what your landscaping goals are. Do what makes sense.
